# Frechet derivative of compact operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, derivatives, banach-spaces, compact-operators

... this seems to be a well known fact as mentioned in [this](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2011-69-1/1/1.pdf) and in [this](http://www.inverseproblems.info/_media/reading%3afreitagpotthast2013.pdf) manuscript.

However, I was not able to find a proof or to prove it by myself.

So my question is: How to prove this?

Any hint or reference is appreciated.

Comment: The classical reference is the book *Topological methods in the theory of nonlinear integral equations* by Krasnoselskii. Not quite easy to find, however...

Comment: The corresponding results that I can find in the book by Krasnoselskii are for weakly continuous functionals. (Thm. 5.1, p. 84) in his [orignal book](http://padabum.com/d.php?id=29416) (in Russian).

Comment: Actually I found this reference in a paper, but I can't access Krasnoselskii's book and I can't read russian at all :-(

Comment: We have an english copy in our library. I will go check tomorrow. Nevertheless, I will reference to your proof below.

Comment: By the way, it seems to me that Krasnoselskii's Lemma 4.1 (page 140) has an almost identical proof.

Comment: Yes, true. So it is all there. Only, Krasnoselskii uses strong continuity here. Which is a bit stronger than compactness. Although, compactness and F-differentiability implies strong continuity...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Theorem.** Let $\Omega$ be an open set in a Banach space $X$ and let $F \in C(\Omega,X)$. If the Fréchet derivative $F'(x_0)$ exists for some $x_0\in\Omega$, then $F'(x_0)$ is a (linear) compact operator.

*Proof.* Assume that $F'(x_0)$ is *not* compact. Then one can find $\epsilon_0>0$ and a sequence $\{y_n\}_n$ such that $\|y_n\|\leq 1$ and 
$$
\|F'(x_0)y_k - F'(x_0)y_l\| \geq \epsilon_0
$$
for $k \neq l$. By definition of the Fréchet derivative, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\|F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)-F'(x_0)h\| \leq \frac{\epsilon_0}{4}\|h\|
$$
provided that $\|h\| < \delta$. Choose $\tau$ such that $\|\tau y_k\|<\delta$ and $x_0+\tau y_k \in \Omega$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
\begin{split}
\|F(x_0+\tau y_k)-F(x_0+\tau y_l)\| & \geq \|F'(x_0) (\tau y_k-\tau y_l)\|-\|F(x_0+\tau y_k)-F(x_0)-F'(x_0)\tau y_k\| \\
&{}-\|F(x_0+\tau y_l)-F(x_0)-F'(x_0)\tau y_l\| \geq \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\tau.
\end{split}
$$ 
But this means that $F$ is not compact on $\Omega$, a contradiction. QED.

Another proof appears in Deimling's book on nonlinear functional analysis. However, it is based on the measure of non-compactness, and it is therefore less direct.

Comment: Hi, i know this question is very old, but i was wondering why is this true : Then one can find $\epsilon_0>0$ and a sequence $\{y_n\}_n$ such that $\|y_n\|\leq 1$ and 
$$
\|F'(x_0)y_k - F'(x_0)y_l\| \geq \epsilon_0
$$
for $k \neq l$.

Comment: ok i got it now. you negated the definition of total boundedness.